# add sharepoint site to windows explorer

Tags: site, explorer, onedrive, windows

I would like to add a SharePoint site to windows explorer under the blue SharePoint icon, so not under the One-drive icon or under the orange SharePoint favorites/sites. I have managed it for a few sites but forgot how I did it. Already trying and searching for hours. Who can help?

So the "sync" button to activate One-drive sync is not what I want

I am using 365 and windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change the SharePoint libraries sync. If your admin made any changes to the sync option it will use your One Drive sync client.

Here is an [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-users-to-sync-SharePoint-files-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-22e1f635-fb89-49e0-a176-edab26f69614?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) about this change.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer, add the SharePoint document library to Trusted Sites.

- In Internet Explorer, select Settings. icon near the top right and then select Internet options.
- Select the Security tab, then select Trusted sites.
- Select Sites.
- Select Add.